# Octave matrix splicing by using vectorization

Tags: octave, vectorization

I have a matrix `A` which is pretty large, and I'd like to compute the function `f` for several sub-matrices of `A`. 
Specifically, I'd like to apply `f` to each sub-matrix `A(:, x:y)`, where `x` and `y` are part of a vector: `v = [x y x y x y x y ...]` and get the results in a vector.
I used a for loop, but it's quite slow and I'd like to know whether it's possible to use vectorization to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your function `f` would already do that for you. Provided that `f()` always returns a single value for any matrix, the following should work:

```
arrayfun (@(x,y) f(A(:,x:y)), V(1:2:end), V(2:2:end))
```